# htaccess redirect with query string modifying

Tags: .htaccess

I have a page like this:
http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1&pnc=5

I want to use htaccess to redirect it to a new static page to be:
http://www.example.com/page-1-5.html

Then !!

if the new page http://www.example.com/page-1-5.html  would be loaded, it would have read & display the original page http://www.example.com/page.php?id=1&pnc=5

Thank you in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page-(\d+)-(\d+)$ page.php?id=$1&pnc=$2
```

Now you should be able to access page.php?id=1&pnc=5 by typing into the address bar page-1-5.